# How to press Alt+Tab programmatically in C# in win 8

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I use this code in VS 2013 in win8 for simulate press Alt+Tab,
but nothing happen.
i test it in win 7 and VS 2012 it's work fine.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private const byte VK_MENU = 0x12;
private const byte VK_TAB = 0x09;
private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x01;
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;

keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0xb8, 0, 0); //Alt Press 
keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0x8f, 0, 0); // Tab Press 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(70);
keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0x8f, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Tab Release 
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0xb8, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Alt Releas
```

How can i solve this problem in win8? 
thanks

Comment: This sounds like it could be complicated. There's a brief (inconclusive) discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b6dbc43-a026-4957-9178-91d2001e2d0d/windows-8-block-alttab-simulation .

Comment: Thank you. seems this is a unresolved problem.... :(

Answer (score 2):

may be its too late to answer but an answered question may help other in future.
Try to send key combination using SendKeys it may work for you.

```
SendKeys.Send("%+{TAB}");
```